# Why isn't there a bucket sort library(or is there?)

Tags: python, java, c++, algorithm, sorting

I've been studying algorithm, and just came across this bucket sort. Although it can only be used for few cases, it just looks too efficient to be not implemented in standard library, since it can sort a list in O(n) time. so my question is, why isn't there a given library that supports bucket sort, or any other counting-sort-like algorithm such as radix sort in most of the languages? I've checked java, python, and c++ library, but it doesn't look like it supports any sorting algorithm other then sorting algorithms based on comparing. 

Although implementing such algorithm requires list to have integer in specific range, it doesn't seem impossible to implement such method. Java, for example, can have a interface similar to Comparator() which returns integer in given range that would be used as index for sorting. So what is the reason that makes O(n) sorting algorithms not used? Or is there a library that actually uses bucket sort that I just missed? Sorry if it was a silly question, I just thought there must be a reason that makes O(n) algorithm unused.

Comment: Probably (just guessing) because you can apply it not just to numbers, but to any type that you decide has a finite set of items that you know how to sort in advance. Having this kind of generalization makes it cumbersome compared to writing your own implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java has a static method `Arrays.sort` that could in principle be implemented as a radix sort for the overloads that accept integer types (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[])). They chose to implement with quicksort. There's no justification given, but I imagine 1. Radix sort requires additional memory, where quicksort doesn't 2. The difference between n log n and n is blunted by the fact that quicksort has good cache locality, where radix sort, less so.

Answer (score 2):

## Java

### Arrays.sort(byte[]), Arrays.sort(short[]) and Arrays.sort(char[])

At least starting from Java 7 are implemented using an in-place [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) with **O(n) time** and **O(1) space** complexities:

```java
static void sort(short[] a, int low, int high) {
  if (high - low > MIN_SHORT_OR_CHAR_COUNTING_SORT_SIZE) {
    countingSort(a, low, high);
  } else {
    sort(a, 0, low, high);
  }
}

private static void countingSort(short[] a, int low, int high) {
  int[] count = new int[NUM_SHORT_VALUES];

  /*
   * Compute a histogram with the number of each values.
   */
  for (int i = high; i > low; ++count[a[--i] & 0xFFFF]);

  /*
   * Place values on their final positions.
   */
  if (high - low > NUM_SHORT_VALUES) {
    for (int i = MAX_SHORT_INDEX; --i > Short.MAX_VALUE; ) {
      int value = i & 0xFFFF;

      for (low = high - count[value]; high > low;
           a[--high] = (short) value
      );
    }
  } else {
    for (int i = MAX_SHORT_INDEX; high > low; ) {
      while (count[--i & 0xFFFF] == 0);

      int value = i & 0xFFFF;
      int c = count[value];

      do {
        a[--high] = (short) value;
      } while (--c > 0);
    }
  }
}
```

[Counting sort implementation](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-14-ga/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/DualPivotQuicksort.java#L2348)

### Arrays.sort(int[]), Arrays.sort(long[]), Arrays.sort(float[]) and Arrays.sort(double[])

There is a ticket [JDK-8266431](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8266431) and a related pull request https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/pull/3938 that intend to switch to radix sort for large arrays.

## Efficiency of radix sort

[Radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) is faster than quicksort or any other comparison-based sorting algorithms both in theory and in practice. There are multiple benchmarks that demonstrate this:

[image: Radix sort is three times faster than quicksort in Java]
[image: Radix sort is 4-6 times faster than quicksort in C++]

https://erik.gorset.no/2011/04/radix-sort-is-faster-than-quicksort.html
https://probablydance.com/2016/12/02/investigating-radix-sort/

Answer (score 0):

Definitely an omission. JgrahT has an implementation, but only for Integer arays. If you want to sort an array of objects from any user-defined class, you will need to go through the key one bit at a time. Thus the class will have to provide a method like getIthKeyBit(). Surprised that this was ignored.